# How to draw a line in line chart for single value in Charts.JS

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js

I need to plot a single value in line chart. Currently i am using charts.JS library for line graph purpose.

The data will be varied some times i'll get the single data inside the data set at that time i need to plot the single value in the line chart.

I had tried with the [charts.js annotation plugin](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation) but it didn't meet my requirements. which is like it wis  overlapping the plotted point in the graph area.

My code

```
createLineChart() {
   this.lineChart = new Chart(this.lineCanvas.nativeElement, {
      type: "line",

      data: {
        labels:[],

        datasets: [
          {
            fill: false,

            backgroundColor: "#0168FF",
            borderColor: "#0168FF",
            pointBackgroundColor: "white", // wite point fill
            pointBorderWidth: 1, // point border width
            lineTension: 0,
            pointBorderColor: "blue",
            pointRadius: 4,
          },
        ],
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          yAxes: [
            {
              ticks: {
                padding: 20,
                beginAtZero: true,
                min: 0,

                stepSize: 100,
              },
              gridLines: {
                drawBorder: false,
              },
            },
          ],
          xAxes: [
            {
             // offset: true,
              ticks: {
                display: false,
               //beginAtZero: true,
               min: 0,

              },
              gridLines: {
                zeroLineColor: "transparent",
                drawBorder: false,
                display: false,
              },
              //offset:true, 
            },
          ],
          legend: {
            display: false,
          },
          tooltips: {
            enabled: false,
          },
        },
          drawTime: "afterDraw", // (default)
        } as ChartOptions,
       // plugins: [ChartAnnotation]
      },
    });
  }
```

To plot the data dynamically:

```
generateRandomDataSet(size) {
    let yaxisArr = [];
    let xaxisArr = [];
    let random_data:any = this.getRandomData(size)
    let maxYTickVal = Math.max.apply(Math, random_data.map((val) => {return val.yaxis}));
    let maxVal = Math.ceil((maxYTickVal+1) / 10) * 10

    for(let data of random_data) {
      yaxisArr.push(data.yaxis)
      xaxisArr.push(data.xaxis)
    }

    this.lineChart.data.datasets[0].data = yaxisArr
    this.lineChart.config.data.labels = []
    this.lineChart.config.data.labels = xaxisArr
    this.lineChart.config.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.max =maxVal
    this.lineChart.config.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.stepSize = maxVal/2

    this.lineChart.update()
  }
```

**What i required**

[image]

**What i am getting**

[image]

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exists different approaches to solve this problem.

1. According to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62132601/2358409) I gave to a similar question, you can define an [`animation.onComplete`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/animations.html#animation-configuration) function to draw the line.
2. In a comment on before mentioned answer, [Lakshmansundeep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3879656/lakshmansundeep) suggested an approach where he defines the same `data` value three times but makes sure, `pointRadius` for the leading and ending data point is zero.

```
datasets: [{
  data: [120, 120, 120],
  ...
  pointRadius: [0, 4, 0],
  pointHoverRadius: [0, 4, 0],
}],
```

For the second approach, please have a look at the code below.

```js
new Chart('line-chart', {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: [null, 'A', null],
    datasets: [{
      data: [120, 120, 120],
      fill: false,
      backgroundColor: "#0168FF",
      borderColor: "#0168FF",
      pointBackgroundColor: "white",
      pointBorderWidth: 1,      
      lineTension: 0,
      pointBorderColor: "blue",
      pointRadius: [0, 4, 0],
      pointHoverRadius: [0, 4, 0],
    }],
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    tooltips: {
      enabled: false
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          padding: 20,
          min: 0,
          stepSize: 100
        },
        gridLines: {
          drawBorder: false
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          display: false
        },
        gridLines: {
          zeroLineColor: "transparent",
          drawBorder: false,
          display: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="line-chart" height="80"></canvas>
```